# Exporting values from a Spreadsheet using Python for webscraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, openpyxl

A. My Objective:

Use Python to extract unique OCPO IDs from an Excel Spreadsheet and using these IDs to web-scrape for corresponding company names and NIN IDs. (Note: Both NIN and OCPO IDs are unique to one company).

B. Details:

i. Extract OCPO IDs from an Excel Spreadsheet using openpyxl.

ii. Search OCPO IDs one-by-one in a business registry (https://focus.kontur.ru/) and find corresponding company names and company IDs (NIN) using BeautifulSoup4.

> Example: A search for OCPO ID "00044428" yields a matching company name ПАО "НК "РОСНЕФТЬ" and corresponding NIN ID "7706107510."

iii. Save in Excel the list of company names and NIN IDs.

C. My progress:
i. I'm able to extract the list of OCPO IDs from Excel to Python.

```
# Pull the Packages
import openpyxl
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Pull OCPO from the Spreadsheet
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"C:\Users\ksong\Desktop\book1.xlsx")
sheet = wb.active
sheet.columns[0]
for cellobjc in sheet.columns[0]:
    print(cellobjc.value)
```

ii. I'm able to search an OCPO ID and let Python scrape matching company name and corresponding company NIN ID.

```
# Part 1a: Pull the Website 
r = requests.get("https://focus.kontur.ru/search?query=" + "00044428")
r.encoding = "UTF-8"
   
# Part 1b: Pull the Content
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser", from_encoding="UTF-8")
    
# Part 2a: Pull Company name
name = soup.find("a", attrs={'class':"js-subject-link"})
name_box = name.text.strip()
print(name_box)
```

D. Help

i. How do you code so that loop each OCPO IDs are searched individually as a loop so that I don't get a list of OCPOs IDs but instead a list of search results? In other words, each OCPO is searched and matched with corresponding Company Name and NIN ID. This loop would have to be fed as `######## ("https://focus.kontur.ru/search?query=" + "########")`.

ii. Also, what code should I use for Python to save all the search results in an Excel Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

1) Create an empty workbook to write to:

```
wb2 = Workbook()
ws1 = wb2.active
```

2) Put all that code in the 2nd box into your for loop from the first box.

3) Change "00044428" to str(cellobjc.value)

4) At the end of each loop, append your row to the new worksheet:

```
row = [cellobjc.value, date_box, other_variables]
ws1.append(row)
```

5) After the loop finishes, save your file

```
wb2.save("results.xlsx")
```